# Resizing ui-layout-east in jQuery UI.Layout Plug-in

Tags: jquery, css

How do you resize `ui-layout-east` in the following jQuery example?

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Layout Example</TITLE>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="jquery.layout-latest.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('body').layout({ applyDefaultStyles: true });

});

</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<DIV class="ui-layout-center">Center
</DIV>
<DIV class="ui-layout-north">North</DIV>
<DIV class="ui-layout-south">South</DIV>
<DIV class="ui-layout-east">East</DIV>
<DIV class="ui-layout-west">West</DIV>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please check the docs for this library.** You're currently including neither the necessary CSS file nor the jQuery UI libray. If you do, your example should work out of the box: http://jsfiddle.net/HVkTD/